# Loading multiple objects complete from database

Tags: php, magento

I have a few thousand dynamic ids of.. lets say products.
Now I want to load these products without sending over thousand queries to the db.
So this is not a solution:

```php
$products = array();
foreach( $ids as $id ){
 $products[] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
}
```

But because I need the *complete* products, this also is not a solution:

```php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addFieldToFilter( 'entity_id', array( 'in', $ids ) );
```

So.. do I *really* have to `load` each single product, which will cause probably *more than 3000 queries* and take a couple of minutes?

Comment: do you really need to have few thousands of products loaded in the same page?

Comment: if you need it, don't! If you are ordered to do so, say you won't. Loading a couple of 1000s on 1 page will cause memory issues on older computers/browsers

Comment: So your question is generally how to get multiple models with one query from the database store?

Comment: @Topener Some data of the products shall get exported, so the clients computer is not my problem, but the servers computer indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach (<product attributes> as <attribute code>) {
    $products->addAttributeToSelect(<attribute code>);
}
```

and after that do

```
$products->addFieldToFilter( 'entity_id', array( 'in', $ids ) );
```

Comment: After that I will have the same as after my second example: A collection of uncomplete product data, or did I misunderstand your answer? Besides: I don't want to seach for `<attribute code>` but for specified ids. But as I said, possibly Im just misunderstanding your answer...

Comment: With `addAttributeToSelect` you can select which model eav attributes should be loaded by collection. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yep, sorry I was really misunderstanding. Everything is clear now. But it is still not a really good solution.. and odd.. but could work for me, thanks for the idea. (=> +1 but not marked as correct)

Comment: I guess there will not come any _correct_ answer so I give up and mark yours as such.